# Use form_for to save data in associated table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am relatively new to rails - therefore the question should be very easy to answer. I tried to find a solution for the problem in other posts, but I could find it (probably because I don't know the right vocabulary right now).

Here is my question/ case:

I have two models:

1) Model one: Users

2) Model two: FreelancerData

They are connect through "User has one FreelancerData" and "FreelancerData belongs_to User". The FreelancerData contains three field "daily_rate", "status" and "user_id" (= foreign field).

Now I want to create a Form with form_for, in which I can fill in the FreelancerData for the current user.

I tried the following code, but this does not work

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit freelancer") %>
<div class="row">   
    <aside class="span4">
        <section>
            <%= render ('layouts/profile') %>
        </section>
    </aside>
    <div class="span8">
        <h1>Edit your profile</h1>
        <h5>Please edit your current working status and your daily rate:</h5>
        <%= form_for @user.freelancer_data do |f| %>

          <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

          <%= f.label :status %>
          <%= f.select :status, ['Busy', 'Available'] %>

            <%= f.label :daily_rate, "Daily rate in Euro ('.' and ',' are not allowed)" %>
          <%= f.text_field :daily_rate %>

          <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: 'btn-large btn-primary' %>

        <% end -%>
        <h5>If you want to change your picture, you can do it here:</h5>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
    <a href="http://gravatar.com/emails">change</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

So my question is: Is it possible to edit data of a associated table FreelancerData through the User Data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup. You can use fields_for. Check out this [link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for).